# Accidentaly disabled keyboard

Tags: command-line, keyboard, xinput

I've got a problem, I tried to disable the touchpad by using:

```
xinput list
xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 0
```

Problem is I put the wrong number, 12 is not the touchpad, but my keyboard. How can I enable it again without using the terminal?

I have Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the terminal again. Just copy and paste with your mouse  the following two lines:

```
xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 1
;
```

Be sure that you copy both lines in the same time!

Comment: Hey, 
thank you!!! 
Yeah copy - paste is a lot easier than trying to type with on-screen keyboard ;)